# Tune Percona Server 5.7

Tags: mysql, percona

I am using a 4 core ubuntu cloud server with 8gb and ssds. There I have only one database for a Magento store which is about 2GB size.
Last month after some changes I made it seems that database performing as it should. Percona server 5.7
After running mysqltuner.pl I have these suggestions:

```
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 4.0M, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_open_cache (> 400)
    thread_pool_size between 16 and 36 for InnoDB usage
    key_buffer_size (> 112.5M)
```

> My.cnf settings are:

```
[mysqld]
user   = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port   = 3306
basedir    = /usr
datadir    = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir   = /dev/shm
lc-messages-dir  = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
skip-name-resolve=1
#skip-grant-tables
log-error    = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_ALL_TABLES
sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
#symbolic-links=0
#
# * Basic Settings
##
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address            = localhost
#bind-address            = 94.237.44.193
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 64M
join_buffer_size        = 4M
max_allowed_packet      = 128M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 128K
thread_pool_size        = 32M
connect_timeout=320 # default 10
table_open_cache = 256M
table_definition_cache  = 256M
sort_buffer_size        = 16M
max_heap_table_size     = 64M
tmp_table_size          = 64M
interactive_timeout     = 3600
max_connections         = 600
max_connect_errors      = 100
#skip_name_resolve
#skip_secure_auth
wait_timeout            = 28800
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4096M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_log_file_size    = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_thread_concurrency  = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit       = 2
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
##table_open_cache       = 3000
#thread_concurrency     = 5
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
##query_cache_limit       = 256M
##query_cache_size        = 64M
##query_cache_type        = 1
```

As you can see with these settings I get: MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high

Can anyone help how to better tune this please?

Comment: You didn't mentioned any resources you used to fine tune your configuration. Here is a good starting point for your scenario: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/

Answer (score 0):

Mysqltuner is pessimistic in the area of "max memory".

8GB is *probably* fine for the settings you have.  But, watch out for "swapping".  If there is swapping, we need to lower some setting(s).

(Move to `dba.stackexchange.com` if you need further advice.)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
join_buffer_size=2M  # from 4M requested per connection
thread_cache_size=100  # from 128K for CAP suggested in 5.7 REFMAN
thread_pool_size=32  # from 32M  a major difference
table_open_cache=1024  # from 256M that would be a LOT of open tables
table_definition_cache=512  # from 256M for shared table definitions all connections
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 16M requested per connection
max_connect_errors=10  # from 100 why give a hacker/cracker so many attempts?
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce CPU cycles used every second for function
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile and we have free Utility Scripts and more suggestions are available.